# sigma-compactness and $\omega$-cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-compact space. An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is said to be an $\omega$-cover if for any finite subset $F$ of $X$ there is a $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $F\subset U.$ **Now my question is if $X$ is $\sigma$-compact then whether every $\omega$-cover of $X$ has a countable subfamily which is again a $\omega$-cover?**

I procced as follows. Let $X=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} K_n,$ each $K_n$ is compact and
$K_{n} \subset K_{n+1}$ for each $n.$ Then for any finite subset $F$ of $X$ there is a $m$ such that $F\subset K_m.$ Also for each $m$ there is a finite subfamily $\mathcal{V}$ of $\mathcal{U}$ such that $F \subset \cup \mathcal{V}$, but how to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this follows, but in a different way than you started out doing: note that $\sigma$-compactness is preserved by finite products, so $X$ being $\sigma$-compact, implies that $X^n$ is too (and thus Lindelöf) for all $n \in \omega$.

So given an $\omega$-cover $\mathcal{U}$ on $X$, for each $n$ we can define the open cover $\mathcal{U}^n = \{ U^n: U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ of $X^n$ (so just form all $n$-fold powers of sets from $\mathcal{U}$; this is a cover of $X^n$ because $\mathcal{U}$ is an $\omega$-cover (!)) and $X^n$ being Lindelöf, we find a countable subcover of $\mathcal{U}^n$. For each $U^n$ we use in the countable subcover we collect $U$ in a new set $\mathcal{V}$ and we do this for all $n$. The result is a countable subfamily (countable union of countable sets)  of $\mathcal{U}$, and it is not too hard too check that it also forms an $\omega$-cover for $X$ (if $F=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a finite subset of $X$, $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is covered by some $U^n$ for $U \in \mathcal{V}$ by construction and then $F \subseteq U$ as required).

So in short: because $X$ is "power-Lindelöf", $X$ has the selection property for $\omega$-covers...  I think that the Sorgenfrey line is a good candidate for a Lindelöf space without this selection property.